# Applying coupons using woocommerce rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing an application using WooCommerce rest `API v3`. Now I'm trying to integrate coupons from my WooCommerce website to my application. I'm creating order and applying coupons like this

```
"coupon_lines":[{
    'code'=>'coupon1',
    'amount'=>'1.00'
}]
```

I've set a usage limit per user in woocommerce website.

When I ordered directly from the website, usage restrictions are applied correctly. i.e, a user cannot use a coupon when a limit is reached.
But when I make an order via REST API, the restrictions are not applied.

Additionally, I got a reply from another forum stating that coupon apply feature is not yet available via rest API. But, while looking through the code of `create_order` API endpoint, I found that the webhook for applying coupon is called there.

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_order_add_coupon', $this->id, $item_id, $code, $discount_amount, $discount_amount_tax );
```

in `add_coupon()`. But I didn't find the `add_action('woocommerce_order_add_coupon',...)` . Can anyone tell me where should I write this action definition so that it shouldn't get overwritten when updating WooCommerce?

Comment: I got reply from another forum stating that coupon apply feature is not yet available via rest api.But, while looking through the code of 'create_order' api endpoint, I found that the webhook for applying coupon is called there.
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_add_coupon', $this->id, $item_id, $code, $discount_amount, $discount_amount_tax );
in add_coupon(). But i didn't find the add_action('woocommerce_order_add_coupon',...). Can anyonetell me where should I write this action definition so that it shouldn't get overwritten when updating woocommerce.

Comment: Write it in a separate plugin file.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add "coupon_lines" to your order object as stated here
Every order should have and "coupon_lines" array containing "id","code","amount" for you desired coupon.

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#view-customer-orders

```
'coupon_lines' => [
    [
        'id' => 55,
        'code' => free50,
        'amount' => '10.75',
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add coupons id and after check?

```
"coupon_lines":[{
        'id' => '',
        'code'=>'coupon1',
        'amount'=>'1.00'
}]
```